# El uso de "se los" en "se los pasó su número"

Tags: pronombres, se

En un grupo de español vi que alguien había puesto la frase:

> Se los pasó su número.

Había alguien que se quería agregar al grupo. Lo que no entiendo es que el "los" se refiera a "ustedes". Lo que yo entiendo del uso de "se lo" es que "se" se usa para representar el objeto indirecto, o en este caso los miembros del grupo, y "lo" se refiere al objeto directo, que en este caso sería el número. Pero al preguntarles, dijeron que "los" se refiere a "ustedes" y "se" se refiere al sujeto, o sea "yo".

¿Alguien me puede explicar por qué es así? También me gustaría ver algunos ejemplos más usando otros verbos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es un error común confundir los pronombres de objeto directo e indirecto, sobre todo en oraciones que no siguen un orden canónico. La oración canónica

> Les pasó su número.

...no presenta ningún problema a un nativo. Es una oración sencilla, donde *les* se refiere a *a ustedes*, el complemento indirecto, y el complemento directo *su número* aparece sin duplicar. En el habla coloquial, sin embargo, se puede repetir el pronombre de complemento directo y decir:

> Se lo pasó su número

...donde *les* se convierte en *se* y *lo* se refiere a *número*. El problema surge a raíz de que mientras que el pronombre *les* es claramente plural, el pronombre *se*, pese a que puede ser singular o plural, "suena" singular. El hablante debe sustituir *a ustedes* con un pronombre que, lógicamente, debe ser plural. Dado que *se* no se puede "pluralizar", se tiende a pluralizar *lo* para convertirlo en *los*. Es un error común incluso en hablantes competentes, sobre todo cuando uno habla rápido y sin poner mucho cuidado en lo que dice, pero que debería identificarse inmediatamente como un error en cuanto se razona un poco. Si las personas que te dijeron que *Se los pasó su número* es correcto aun lo creen después de preguntarles al respecto, mi consejo es que no les hagas mucho caso en cuestiones de gramática.